# What is the complexity (big / little o) of the ArcGIS watershed delineation algorithm?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, algorithm, watershed

I'm curious about the complexity, in terms of [Big or little O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), of watershed delineation algorithms that are implemented in ArcGIS.  I imagine that these will be dependent on either the size of the input raster or on the size of the basin being delineated, but I am not sure.